# Properly typing Prismic Content Relationships

Tags: typescript, next.js, prismic.io

I am trying to build a mega menu for a my header but am running into a type error and was wondering if anyone had run into this and how you solved it? I am importing the generated types from `@/prismicio-types`.

My client query looks like:

```
export default async function getHeaderSettings(
  client: Client<AllDocumentTypes>
): Promise<HeaderDocument<string>> {
  return client.getSingle('header', {
    graphQuery: `
          {
              header {
                  logo
                  menu {
                      label
                      is_link
                      link
                      submenu {
                          cta_image
                          menu {
                              item {
                                  ...itemFields
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      `,
  });
}
```

Which is called and the appropriate data is passed into the header:

```
interface IHeader {
  data: Simplify<HeaderDocumentData>;
}
```

However when I try to access the data in the submenu I receive the following:

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'ContentRelationshipField<"header_submenu">'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'EmptyLinkField<"Document">'.
```

```
const formatHeaderData = (data: Simplify<HeaderDocumentData>) => {
  const { menu, logo } = data;

  const formattedMenu = menu.length
    ? menu.map((item) => {
        return {
          label: item.label,
          is_link: item.is_link,
          link: item.link,
          submenu: {
            cta_image: item.submenu.data.cta_image,
            menu: item.submenu.data.menu.map((subMenuItem) => {
              return {
                menu_label: subMenuItem.item.data.menu_label,
                menu: subMenuItem.item.data.menu,
              };
            }),
          },
        };
      })
    : [];
  
  return {
    logo,
    menu: formattedMenu,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `HeaderDocument` type doesn't automatically contain the types for the content relationship fields. The best solution I've found to this is to embellish the return type of the `getHeaderSettings` function.

An example for one level of nesting (you will have to add the further levels):

```js
import type { Content } from '@prismicio/client';

type HeaderWithMenuDocument =
  Content.HeaderDocument & {
    data: {
      menu: Content.MenuDocument;
    };
  };
```

then you can change the return type of your function

```js
export default async function getHeaderSettings(
  client: Client<AllDocumentTypes>
): Promise<HeaderWithMenuDocument>
```